# Parsing INNODB STATUS in java with regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to parse the INNODB status in java using regular expressions. I am trying to extract the information regarding deadlocks. I'm trying to get the information related to deadlocks. I'm using the following regex, to get the block of text related to LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK.

```
String innodbStatus =  <required_INNODB_status>; // assume this is the text
String multiLineRegEx = "((.*)(?:(?:\r\n|[\r\n]))*)*";
String newLineCharacter = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String myRegEx = "[-]+" + newLineCharacter + deadLockLabel + newLineCharacter + "[-]+" +  newLineCharacter + multiLineRegEx + "[-]+";

assertTrue(innodbStatus.matches(myRegEx));
```

I'm not sure how to extract the multiline text, i.e. the text related to deadlocks from the entire innodb status. The above test passes, but the following code does not return the required string I am looking for...

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(multiLineRegEx);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(targetFileStr);
if (matcher.find())
{
  String requiredString = matcher.group(1));
}
```

Any suggestions on how to extract that the required text.
Sample INNODB status, which I am trying to parse..

```
=====================================
130502 14:18:59 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 27 seconds
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
060717  4:16:48
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 0 42313619, ACTIVE 49 sec, process no 10099, OS thread id 3771312 starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 320
MySQL thread id 30898, query id 100626 localhost root Updating
update iz set pad='a' where i=2
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 16403 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `test/iz` trx id 0 42313619 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 5 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000002; asc     ;; 1: len 6; hex 00000285a78f; asc       ;; 2: len 7; hex 00000040150110; asc    @   ;; 3: len 10; hex 61202020202020202020; asc a         ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 0 42313620, ACTIVE 24 sec, process no 10099, OS thread id 4078512 starting index read, thread declared inside InnoDB 500
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
3 lock struct(s), heap size 320
MySQL thread id 30899, query id 100627 localhost root Updating
update iz set pad='a' where i=1
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 16403 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `test/iz` trx id 0 42313620 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 5 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000002; asc     ;; 1: len 6; hex 00000285a78f; asc       ;; 2: len 7; hex 00000040150110; asc    @   ;; 3: len 10; hex 61202020202020202020; asc a         ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 16403 n bits 72 index `PRIMARY` of table `test/iz` trx id 0 42313620 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;; 1: len 6; hex 00000285a78e; asc       ;; 2: len 7; hex 000000003411d9; asc     4  ;; 3: len 10; hex 61202020202020202020; asc a         ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)

----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
```

Comment: What lines are important from this text?

Comment: Time of deadlock and Transactions (ids and queries) involved in the deadlock..
I first tried getting the text for the deadlock information. The next step would be to extract this information, from that text.. or would it be better to directly extract this information from the entire innodb status ..?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex appears to be trying to match and capture the text between the lines made up of dashes after having found an acceptable header/prefix to start matching from (deadLockLabel - assumed to be initialised to something like `LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK` since it's missing from your code).

I'd recommend the following:

- change `[-]+` to just `-+` - the []s are superfluous.
- add `+ newLineCharacter` to the end of the regex such that the text you want to capture is between full lines of only -'s and not just a - sequence that happens to appear somewhere at the start of a line.
- ideally, replace the use of newLineCharacter with ^ and $ as appropriate by passing the `MULTILINE` flag.
- replace the regex for capturing the text with something more like: `((?:.*(?:\r\n|\r|\n))+?)` (note the ungreedyness of the + operator), or better yet, with just `(.+?)` and pass the `DOTALL` flag.

The resulting optimised regex would look like this:

```
^-{4,}+(?:\r\n|\r|\n)LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK(?:\r\n|\r|\n)-{4,}+(?:\r\n|\r|\n)(.+)-{4,}+$
```

I insist that lines of dashes be at least 4 long to count and tell it to be possessive about consuming the dashes, and the above will require the passing of both the `MULTILINE` and `DOTALL` flags.